# How to delay the execution process after the API limit exceeeds

Tags: c#, api, c#-4.0, azure-functions

I have created a Azure function to pull the data through api calls and loading int Azure table. Since the data is huge each time the API limits exceeds. The limit of the API calls is 300 per minutes. So i'm thinking if we delay the process after 290 API calls for a minute, the process will continue from the queue in next minute.

Please advise whether above logic will work?

Below is the code, I don't see the below code is delaying the process. Please advise.

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */60 * * * *")]TimerInfo 
myTimer,TraceWriter log)
    {
      const string StorageAccountName=""
      const string StorageAccountKey=""
      CloudTable tableReference1 = 
storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference("APIcounttable");
tableReference1.CreateIfNotExists((TableRequestOptions)null, 
(OperationContext)null);
        int num = new Random().Next(1, 999999999);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
tableReference1.Execute(TableOperation.Insert((ITableEntity)new CountAPICalls(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfffffff")+num.ToString())
        {

            API = "APIcall",

        }), 

 (TableRequestOptions)null, (OperationContext)null);

 if (tableReference1.ExecuteQuery<CountAPICalls>(new 
 TableQuery<CountAPICalls>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Key","eq", "APIcall")), (TableRequestOptions)null,(OperationContext)null).ToList<CountAPICalls>().Count<CountAPICalls>()>290)
  { 
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); 
  }
```

Comment: Before trying to answer this I would like you to properly format the code so it is readable.

Comment: Apologies peter, Updated the code format.

Comment: If your function runs long and you have multiple instances (by timer) you should increase the timer in order to have less multiple executions. In order to better control your IO outbound try SemaphoreSlim to control the maximum outgoing connections from a single instance.